# Using querySelector in JavaScript, not working in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a Hangman game and I can't get the incorrect guessed letters to appear on my HTML page.

In JavaScript I have:

```
//Array of available words
const words = ["patriots", "bills", "dolphins", "jets", "chiefs", "chargers", "raiders", "broncos", "steelers", "ravens", "bengals", "browns", "jaguars", "titans", "colts", "texans", "eagles", "cowboys", "redskins", "giants", "rams", "seahawks", "cardinals", "niners", "vikings", "lions", "packers", "bears", "saints", "panthers", "falcons", "buccaneers"];

let currentWord;
let dashes = [];
let rightLetter = [];
let wrongLetter = [];

//Computer chooses a random word from the words array. The random choice becomes currentWord
function startGame() {
  currentWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

  //test
  console.log(currentWord)

  //Creates underscores depending on length of the currentWord; push underscores to dashes array 
  for (let i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
    dashes.push(' _ ');
  }
  return dashes;

  let formattedDashes = dashes.join(' ');
  document.getElementByClassName('dashContainer').innerHTML = formattedDashes;
}

//test
console.log(startGame());

//HTML document waits for key to be pressed; key is assiged Unicode value (a/A are diff)
document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  let codes = event.keyCode;

  //Convert a Unicode value into a character
  let characters = String.fromCharCode(codes);

  //Search currentWord for the users correct guess; push character to rightLetter array
  if (currentWord.indexOf(characters) > -1)
    rightLetter.push(characters);

  //Replace dashes with correctly choosen characters
  dashes[currentWord.indexOf(characters)] = characters;
  console.log(dashes);



  //Search currentWord for the users incorrect guess; push character to wrongLetter array
  if (currentWord.indexOf(characters) < 0)
    wrongLetter.push(characters);
  //Test        
  console.log(wrongLetter);
})

//Start game function
//startGame()


//Test Example
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function () {
  alert("Good Luck!")


  document.querySelector(".wrong").innerHTML = wrongLetter;

})
```

wrongLetter is an empty array and the letters are showing up there in console.log. My HTML page has

```
<div class="wrong"></div>
```

There are no errors in console.log either. Any ideas why this might not be working?

Thanks

Comment: `wrongLetter is an empty array and the letters are showing up there in console.log`..........but how?

Comment: _"letters are showing up there in console.log"_ <- **how?** You have no `console.log()` calls in your one line of code

Comment: if(currentWord.indexOf(characters) < 0)
        wrongLetter.push(characters);
//Test        
        console.log(wrongLetter);
    })

Comment: Please add that to your question instead of in a comment

Comment: If I had to guess, you only ever call `.innerHTML = wrongLetter` once, somewhere early on in your script's execution. Later on you probably add letters to `wrongLetter` but you never change the content of your `<div>`

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript in your question. Please update it with actual code

Comment: Can you show us more of your code? or write it in jsFiddle

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. First time here.

Comment: Looks exactly like in [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853051/using-queryselector-in-javascript-not-working-in-html#comment90658685_51853051). You never update the content of your _wrong_ `<div>` unless you keep clicking the _start_ element

Comment: Also, you're `return`-ing out of your `startGame` function too early

Comment: Sidenote: let formattedDashes = dashes.join(' '); and the line after that never gets called due to your return statement of return dashes;

Comment: Phil, thank you for your insight. So after wrongLetter.push(characters); I need to update wrongLetter?

Comment: noa-dev: are you saying I should remove return dashes?